# Produce a value in one cell, if another cell contains a specific text in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an excel file that has 1000 rows. I would like to insert certain values in a specific column if another column contains a certain text string.

```
name    value
hello
ok
sure
hello
```

Where ever there is the word hello I would like 33, for ok I'd like 32 and for sure I'd like 34 to be added to its value.

Doing: (in excel)

```
=IF(B5=$B$4,33,"")
```

[image]

Doing in Pandas:

```
mask = df['value'].str.contains(r'hello', na=True)
df.loc[mask, '33'] = df['value']
```

This works, but how would I include the other criteria? The formula keeps saying I have too many arguments.

[image]

Desired

```
name    value
hello   33
ok      32
sure    34
hello   33
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)?

```
df['value'] = df['name'].map({'hello':33, 'ok':32, 'sure':34})
```